# How to mute Speech Recognizer's beep sound?

Tags: react-native, react-native-voice

In *React native*, when I start speech recognition it gives *beep sound*.

Code that I used to start recognition :

```
 _startRecognizing = async() => {
        try {
            await Voice.start();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
```

*Library used* : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-voice

**Is there any way to mute this Beep sound in android?**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no solution to this request yet
See [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-voice/issues/127)